# jQuery lazy load images

Tags: jquery, image, lazy-loading

I try to lazy load images with jQuery, but does not seems to work properly, sometimes I get the placeholder even if there is image

```
   $(window).on('load', function() {
        var defaultImage = $('.lazy-load').each(function(){
            if($(this).get(0).naturalWidth < 2 ) {
                $(this).addClass('image-placeholder');
                $(this).attr('src', 'no-image.jpg')
            }
        })
    });
```

What I'm missing?